# Openpyxl: read spreadsheet data in a range of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Hello I am trying to read data from a spreadsheet in a range which includes row 2 to 5 and it follows the column order but I keep getting error saying there is something wrong with the column range can anyone help me? 
The code should look like this but instead of rows it should be columns:

```
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
   state  = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
   county = sheet['C' + str(row)].value
   pop    = sheet['D' + str(row)].value
```

the code I have attempted is:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('name of wb')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for col in range('G', sheet.max_column + 1):
   state  = sheet[1 + str(column)].value
   county = sheet[2 + str(column)].value
   pop    = sheet[3 + str(column)].value
   hospitals  = sheet[4 + str(column)].value
   universities = sheet[5 + str(column)].value
```

Comment: Can you post the code you attempted and an example of the spreadsheet might help too.

Comment: I have uploaded the code in the description of the problem

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your code "sheet.max_row + 1" is the culprit.  That would go OUTSIDE of the indexable range of your sheet list.

Comment: I have uploaded the code in the description of the problem

Comment: You uploaded the code, but your original question states: "The code should look like this but instead of rows it should be columns"

Where is your attempt of using rows instead of columns?

Answer (score 0):

The problem as far as I can see is in "range('G', sheet.max_column + 1)". Arguments for range usually should be integers.
Check out a couple of methods in the openpyxl utils module:

column_index_from_string(str_col), 
get_column_letter(idx,)

for your example, column_index_from_string('G') gives 7. You should also turn your cell references into excel style e.g. A1 not 1A.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('name of wb')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for col in range(openpyxl.utils.column_index_from_string('G'), sheet.max_column + 1):
   state  = sheet[openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(col) + '1'].value
   county = sheet[openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(col) + '2'].value
   pop    = sheet[openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(col) + '3'].value
   hospitals  = sheet[openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(col) + '4'].value
   universities = sheet[openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(col) + '5'].value
```